# Create User Defined Type In SMO

Tags: smo

How Create User Defined Type (ex: Point(X int,Y int) With SMO?
I Am Use VB.NET (Or C#.NET) And Want Use SMO For Create?
I know must use "UserDefinedType" in SMO but i don't know How?!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By using following code sample you can create UserDefinedType using SMO:

```
Dim oServer As Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server
Dim oSMOServer As Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server
Dim oSMODatabase As Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database
Dim sUDT As String = "udt_RecordID"

Try
    oServer = New Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server()
    ''Set ServerName
    oServer.ConnectionContext.ServerInstance = pServerInstanceName  
    ''Set is Windows Authentication
    oServer.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = pIsWinAuth  

    ''Set Server UserName & Password, If not Windows Authentication
    If pIsWinAuth = False Then
        oServer.ConnectionContext.Login = pUsername
        oServer.ConnectionContext.Password = pPassword
    End If

    Dim oUDTs = oSMOServer.Databases(pDatabaseName).UserDefinedTableTypes

    ''Add UserDefinedType if not exist
    If Not oUDTs.Contains(sUDT) Then
        oSMODatabase = oSMOServer.Databases(pDatabaseName)
        Dim udtt As UserDefinedTableType
        udtt = New UserDefinedTableType(oSMODatabase, sUDT)

        ''Add necessary columns
        udtt.Columns.Add(New Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column(udtt, "RecordID", DataType.NVarChar(50)))

        ''Create UserDefinedType
        udtt.Create()
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    ''Handle Exception
End Try
```

Feel free to ask if required.

Comment: Hi my friend.Thanks for the answer but one problem :this code was for create a user-defined table types.I want create a user-defined types in SQL Server with SMO.Thanks very much again.